# Dynamic Data in TabLayout and Viewpager Fragment is Out of sync

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I have a `TabLayout`, where the data is populated from web service which contain `{"TOPS","LAUNDRY","BEDDING"...}`.

This data is stored in a list which is passed into the adapter.

```
myTabAdapter = new MyTabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),tabListings);
viewpager.setAdapter(myTabAdapter);
tabList.setupWithViewPager(viewpager);
```

And my `TabAdapter`.

```
public class MyTabAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private ArrayList<TabListing> tabListings;
    String item;
    private Bundle bundle;

    public MyTabAdapter(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager, ArrayList<TabListing> tabListings) {
        super(supportFragmentManager);
        this.tabListings = tabListings;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            TabListing l = tabListings.get(position);
            String a = l.getName();
            bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("item", a);
            return OneFragment.newInstance(0, bundle);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabListings.size();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            TabListing l = tabListings.get(position);
            String a = l.getName();
        return a;
    }
}
```

In the `getItem()` method I am passing the name using bundle to fragment with new instance method.

When the data gets into the fragment like "TOPS", it is to be passed in the database Reference field of `Firebase` to populate my `recyclerview`.

My problem is when i run the app, the get the data for "LAUNDRY" instead of "TOPS" in the first run. When I swipe 2 index forward to "BEDDING", the data is synced according to the tabs. I cannot understand what is the problem.

My Fragment class.

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment {

    private static String a;
    RecyclerView recyclerview;
    AdapterToActivity act;
    Bundle args;
    ListingAdapter adapter;
    FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;
    DatabaseReference mReference;
    ContentLoadingProgressBar pBar;
    int position;
    ArrayList<ItemList> itm = new ArrayList<>();

    public OneFragment() {
    }

    public static OneFragment newInstance(int position, Bundle item) {
        Bundle args = item;
        a = args.getString("item");
        OneFragment fragment = new OneFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        recyclerview = v.findViewById(R.id.all_product_list);
        pBar = v.findViewById(R.id.progress);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 1);
        recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter = new ListingAdapter(getActivity(),itm,a);
        args = getArguments();
        RecyclerViewAdapterMethod();
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        pBar.show();

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        pBar.hide();
    }

    private void RecyclerViewAdapterMethod() {
        pBar.show();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mReference = mDatabase.getReference(a);
        mReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                ItemList l;
                l = dataSnapshot.getValue(ItemList.class);
                itm.add(l);
                recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                pBar.hide();
                }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```